# Achieve reusable Button

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I want to know how could I achieve this:

In one dialog I have a button with an image:

```
    <Button>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="Save"/> // Image for this button (floppy disk)
            <TextBlock Text="Add customer"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

This should be a default 'save button' in my project. How can I make this reusable? At the moment I have to copy this code in another context lets say add article:

```
    <Button>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="Save"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Add article"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

I want one place where I can change it and effects every 'save' button in my whole project. I have tried ControlTemplate but if I use it the system's default design of the button disappears. But I want the system's default design.

Comment: you should use content template http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this with a style.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="saveButton">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="24" Height="24" Source="{StaticResource Save}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then use your buttons:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Save" Style="{StaticResource saveButton}"/>
    <Button Content="Add article" Style="{StaticResource saveButton}"/>
</Grid>
```

Replace the `Image`s in your resource dictionary with `BitmapImage`s:

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="Images/MenuIcons/File.png" x:Key="File" />
```

Comment: True, though you also could make it as the App.Resources or another Shared ResourceDictionary

Comment: Hey dymaniod, thank you very much it works as I want. But I have another problem in this case: I have a resource Dictionary where I have the images for my project. In this dictionary is a style for images with their height and width to 24. This style doesn't work for your solution... So my floppy disk image is 32x32 but should be 24 like I have defined it in my 'IconDictionary'. Can you help me?

Comment: my own answer is for 'Can you provide your dictionary xaml code?'. It should be a better place than this comment.

Comment: @Icepickle, I've placed that in the `Window.Resources` only for demonstration purpose. Of course, the style may be defined in any resource dictionary or even directly in any `FrameworkElement` depending on what the question author wants.

Answer (score 0):

IconDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="24" />
</Style>

<!--MENU_ICONS:-->
<Image Source="../Images/MenuIcons/KraftSolution.ico" x:Key="KraftSolution" />
<Image Source="../Images/MenuIcons/File.png" x:Key="File" />
<Image Source="../Images/MenuIcons/Close.png" x:Key="Close" />
<Image Source="../Images/MenuIcons/Customers.png" x:Key="Customers"  />
<Image Source="../Images/MenuIcons/Vehicles.png" x:Key="Vehicles"  />
<Image Source="../Images/MenuIcons/Components.png" x:Key="Components"  />
<Image Source="../Images/MenuIcons/Connection.png" x:Key="Connection"  />
<Image Source="../Images/MenuIcons/Info.png" x:Key="Info" />

<!--MENU_OPERATIONS:-->

<!--CUSTOMER:-->
<Image Source="../Images/MenuOperations/Customer/Customer_Add.png" x:Key="CustomerAdd" />
<Image Source="../Images/MenuOperations/Customer/Customer_Edit.png" x:Key="CustomerEdit" />
<Image Source="../Images/MenuOperations/Customer/Customer_Delete.png" x:Key="CustomerDelete" />

<!--VEHICLE:-->
<Image Source="../Images/MenuOperations/Vehicle/Vehicle_Add.png" x:Key="VehicleAdd" />
<Image Source="../Images/MenuOperations/Vehicle/Vehicle_Edit.png" x:Key="VehicleEdit" />
<Image Source="../Images/MenuOperations/Vehicle/Vehicle_Delete.png" x:Key="VehicleDelete" />

<!--COMPONENT:-->
<Image Source="../Images/MenuOperations/Component/Component_Add.png" x:Key="ComponentAdd" />
<Image Source="../Images/MenuOperations/Component/Component_Edit.png" x:Key="ComponentEdit" />
<Image Source="../Images/MenuOperations/Component/Component_Delete.png" x:Key="ComponentDelete" />

<!--TAB CONTROL:-->
<Image Source="../Images/MenuIcons/Notes.png" x:Key="Notes" />
<Image Source="../Images/MenuIcons/Contact.png" x:Key="Contact" />

<!--SEARCH_BUTTON:-->
<Image Source="../Images/MenuIcons/Search.png" x:Key="Search" />

<Image Source="../Images/MenuOperations/Save.png" x:Key="Save" Height="24" Width="24"/>
<Image Source="../Images/MenuOperations/Abort.png" x:Key="Abort" />
```

To solve my problem I have added Height="24" Width="24" to the Save-Image. But I don't want that. I want one position where I can control the image size.

Your style is in another resource dictionary and I have both dictionaries included in my window where I use the button and images.

Comment: You are free to place the styles in any resource dictionary you want. I have extended my answer, so you could define your image size directly in the `Button`'s `ContentTemplate`.

Comment: Thank you! One last question for this topic (I hope): Why should I use <BitmapImage> instead of <Image> what are the advantages?

Comment: A `BitmapImage` is a `BitmapSource` (an object that is optimized for loading images using **xaml**), so you can use it as an image source in any `Image` control in your application. It has additional properties like `DecodePixelWidth` which may be very useful. An `Image` is a `FrameworkElement`, so you cannot use it as a source anywhere else. This is a **control** that displays an image